# how to write a map as a json object in c++

Tags: c++, json

I have a to write a data into the json key and corresponding to that the value. My key is a structure with  two values { int id & char * name}, my value is also a structure with three values { int a, int b, int c }. I intend to put the key in json as { id:name }, and value also separated by delimiter { a:b:c }

How is the conversion done from c++ structure to a json object?  and read this created json object as a map again.

Comment: Well, you need to pick a JSON kit for C++.  There are a bunch listed at json.org.  Then you will create your data as a "nest" of C++ "map" and "list" objects, the specific classes varying with the kit you choose.  But first go to json.org and spend the 5 minutes it takes to learn JSON syntax.

Comment: { a:b:c } is not json syntax, and key can not be an object, key can only be double quoted string. see [here](http://w3schools.com/json/default.asp) to learn the syntax of JSON

Comment: So if I want to put a variable with these values, I can convert them to a string and then insert as key. String a = strcat(id.toString(),name) similarly the value also I may put as string ( say var b) and then have a object say {
"mymap": [
{ "key":a , "value":b }]}

Comment: @DanielKing - The JSON description at json.org is far easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second @Hot Licks about spending 5 minutes to learn the JSON syntax. Maybe even C++.

Assuming a key structure with id=1234 and name='nandini', it will be serialized to:

```
"{ 'id': 1234, 'name': 'nandini' }"
```

Ditto for the value structure, that will NOT have the format as you suggested but something like (for a structure with values 1, 2, and 3):

```
"{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }"
```

Serialization is easy. You can use whatever string building technique you like, including any variant of sprintf, or stringstream. You can of course use a Json library.

As for the mapping part, Json (or JavaScript for that matter) do not support a keys other than strings, like other languages. If you are using a library that supports std::map - then use it. Otherwise, you can come with something like an array of objects or similar. e.g.

```
"[ { key: {...}, val: {...} }, { key: {...}, val: {...} },    ...    ]
```

Then, upon deserialization, put the array into a map.

Deserialization will be trickier, and you should definitely look at a Json library. Take a look of the JSON parsers on [JSON.org](http://json.org)

Comment: @nandini - The above is (close as I can tell) correct.  Most importantly you need to understand the distinction between "objects" (containing unordered sets of key/value pairs) and "arrays" (containing lists of individual items).  And even when you're creating a relatively simple string you might as well use the tools, so you'll become familiar with them -- you pretty much have to use the tools on the receiving end.